# How to get .crt and .key files from Azure App Configuration

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-app-configuration

I have a key vault where I store one certificate. For now I was using CSI driver to get it from the key vault and mount it in my pod. It showed like this: **cert**, **cert.crt**, **cert.key**.
I would like to use from now, Azure App Configuration. So I created reference to this certificate and tried to mount it, but I'm only getting one file **cert**.
Is there any way to get also **.crt** and **.key** files? I need to use them in my .NET application which is in the same pod.

I tried to add reference in different ways and also I was searching information in documentation but didn't found nothing about Azure App Configuration and storing certificates reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're using the [App Configuration .NET provider library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureAppConfiguration), which is designed to get the secret value of a Key Vault secret or certificate. For both secrets and certificates, your application's `IConfiguration` is populated with the [KeyVaultSecret.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.security.keyvault.secrets.keyvaultsecret.value?view=azure-dotnet#azure-security-keyvault-secrets-keyvaultsecret-value) property. In case of Key Vault certificates, this secret value already contains both public and private keys of the certificate, but this value needs to be parsed to get individual public/private keys. To give you some idea, this code sample from Key Vault shows how to parse the secret value: [Get a Certificate Including the Private Key](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/keyvault/samples/getcert/Program.cs).

```
private static X509Certificate2 ParseCertificate(KeyVaultSecret secret)
{
    if (string.Equals(secret.Properties.ContentType, CertificateContentType.Pkcs12.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        byte[] pfx = Convert.FromBase64String(secret.Value);
        return new X509Certificate2(pfx);
    }

    // For PEM, you'll need to extract the base64-encoded message body.
    // .NET 5.0 introduces the System.Security.Cryptography.PemEncoding class to make this easier.
    if (string.Equals(secret.Properties.ContentType, CertificateContentType.Pem.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        ...
        ...
```

As you can see, the parsing logic also relies on `KeyVaultSecret.Properties.ContentType`, which is not available if you use App Configuration provider library.

So the best option would be to resolve certificate references using [App Configuration .NET SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.AppConfiguration). This library returns the raw KeyVault certificate reference that you store in App Configuration and you can resolve the reference yourself:

```cs
Response<ConfigurationSetting> response = client.GetConfigurationSetting("MyCertificateReference");
if (response.Value is SecretReferenceConfigurationSetting secretReference)
{
    var identifier = new KeyVaultCertificateIdentifier(secretReference.SecretId);
    var certificateClient = new CertificateClient(identifier.VaultUri, new DefaultAzureCredential());
    var cert = await certificateClient.GetCertificateAsync(identifier.Name);
}
```

Comment: You are right. The public and private key were stored already inside the secret, soo everything what I needed to do was to create object `var X509Certificate2 x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(CERT_PATH)` and then use it as I want.